# BindingSource parameters

Tags: c#, bindingsource

Code for binding source:

```
Component.DataSource = new BindingSource(yourSource, ????);
```

All the examples that I saw follow this patter, and instead of ????, I always see a null.
The Docs say the parameters are data source and data member, but I don't understand what is the purpose of the data member or how to use it.

Comment: the second param is a string where you can specify a specific column or list member name to bind to. you can find more by just reading the MSDN docs on the BindingSource constructor you're talking about, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158150.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataMember` parameter is used when the source contains multiple columns, lists, or tables of data and you need to specify which one is being used.  From the [MSDN for the DataMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datamember.aspx):

> If the DataSource contains multiple lists (or tables) of data, you
>   should set the DataMember property to the name of one of the sources.

The constructor that you are asking about simply allows you to specify this property at instantiation.